# How to describe something that's slower than it could be, but it guarantees success eventually?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to name a module in a piece of software. The module *guarantees* the delivery of messages sent on a network connection that's only available intermittently, and makes no guarantees about *when* the delivery might be.

Is there a word than can sum up that behaviour? I've toyed with 'best-effort' but that implies the opposite of guaranteed delivery.

Comment: _Slow and steady does the job._

Comment: It would require playing loose with hyphenation but there's "When-not-if."

Comment: *Slow but sure* (but I vote for @JohnLawler's comment-answer).

Comment: Slow but sure is better.  The network in the OP is not slow and steady, it is intermittent but persistent.

Comment: I would go with slow-but-sure, I think that's plain English and effectively tells the reader what it does. Though I guess the problem is that it implys that the connection is _always_ slow, which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: "Robust" implies guaranteed action, but does not imply anything about speed.

Comment: (Is there anything wrong with "guaranteed delivery" or "guaranteed action" or whatever?)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word **assured**, as in "assured eventual delivery"

Comment: *ensured* might be a better fit.  And I won't say you need to quote a dictionary, but you do need to explain why the suggestion fits the question.

Comment: Or "assured mutual destruction".

Answer (score 0):

If  messages stay offline, I think about **postpone**. **1.** to put off or delay until a future time
**2.** to put behind in order of importance; defer

Answer (score 0):

Delayed Job/Worker

**Delayed:** make (someone or something) late or slow. There's also a Ruby gem called [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) which does exactly this. Both of the other answers are perfect in terms of meeting your definition for *put off til later* but I think this answer works better because the others become clunker to remember once you try to name a `Class` after them: `postponedJob`, `assuredWorker`, `assuredActivity`, `postponedTask`.

Answer (score 0):

The system you are describing could be called [fault tolerant](http://foldoc.org/fault%20tolerant).

From FOLDOC:

> fault tolerance: The ability of a system or component to continue normal operation despite the presence of hardware or software faults. This often involves some degree of redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to name a module in a piece of software. The module
>   guarantees the delivery of messages sent on a network connection
>   that's only available intermittently, and makes no guarantees about
>   when the delivery might be.

The closest technical term for this is [reliable messaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_messaging):

> Reliable messaging is the concept of communicating messages across an
>   unreliable infrastructure whilst being able to make certain guarantees
>   about the successful transmission of the messages; for example, that
>   if the message is delivered, it is delivered at most once, or that all
>   messages successfully delivered arrive in a particular order.

The caveat is that reliable messaging assumes you can provide some guarantee of the message delivery process.

Now, I don't know of a single word that would define this, but as it is an accepted term in the software networking domain, you may say *"the module implements reliable messaging"*.

I initially thought of suggesting ***measured*** because it concentrates on the slowness of it, but I believe in your case you shouldn't concentrate on the slow part (because this is not really a defining factor of your module), the key component is the *guarantee* which *may result* in the slowness of the system.

In other words, the slowness may not happen, as long as the guarantee is enforced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it (finally) inspired me to think of the name Tortoise!